# How to remove a component from the different language version in sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I am running into this weird issue where i can remove a component from a page for default language and add it back whereas for other language versions like en-de or en-gb; when i remove the component and save it, The component still remains there.
Has anyone run into this issue ?

Comment: It's difficult to tell what might be wrong. Have you checked log files?

Comment: Look at the raw values of __Renderings and the __Final Renderins for each language of the item to identify what rendering deltas are applied. That could be a start. Also, check the standard values of the two field. If __Final Renderings is not null on the standard values it may play tricks with you

Comment: Language Fallback enabled?